# Creating looped page breaks in R Markdown for HTML publication

Tags: r, slidy

I am using R Markdown to create an HTML presentation (specifically, where output is slidy_presentation). I am trying to write a loop to print a set of charts per country, with a new page for each set. However, I'm having trouble inserting the page break. All the guides I have seen refer only to how to create a page break if generating a PDF (variants of using `cat("\n\\newpage\n")`, and also specifying `{r results = "asis"}`), but this doesn't work if I'm generating HTML for Slidy. Alternatively, if I try to use `cat("##")` to output the code used in R Markdown for a newpage, I also don't get the right result.

Are there any suggestions on how I can write this loop?

Answer (score 1):

I've done

```
for(i in some_vector){
    cat("\n\n## slide title: ", i, "\n")
    more code...
}
```

and that works for me